# Ability to easily manage attributes in Solidity Struct

Tags: solidity, dapp-development, dapps, dapp-design

Below is a very simple smart contract which has a struct Instructor which has 3 attributes right now i.e. `age`, `fName`, and `lName`. Now if tomorrow I wish to add a new attribute I will need to update all the places where this struct was being used in the respective smart contract, which is a bad point from scalability and code maintenance perspective.

so question, Is there a better way of handling this situation?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Courses {

struct Instructor {
    uint age;
    string fName;
    string lName;
}

mapping (address => Instructor) instructors;
address[] public instructorAccts;

function setInstructor(address _address, uint _age, string _fName, string _lName) public {
    instructors[_address].age = _age;
    instructors[_address].fName = _fName;
    instructors[_address].lName = _lName;

    instructorAccts.push(_address) -1;
}

function getInstructors() view public returns(address[]) {
    return instructorAccts;
}

function getInstructor(address _address) view public returns (uint, string, string) {
    return (instructors[_address].age, instructors[_address].fName, instructors[_address].lName);
}

function countInstructors() view public returns (uint) {
    return instructorAccts.length;
}

}
```

Comment: You could include an 'extraInfo' bytes[] field in your struct and pass it any additional data in json format - this might not be the tidiest way of doing it though so I'm interested in seeing any other ways people can come up with!

Comment: I thought of it as well, something which we use a lot of time in a web application, to handle dynamic fields is storing JSON in the database as a column for metaData but the challenge I see here in Solidity is that might lead a lot of iteration or IF/ELSE check in the JSON for newly added columns or old removed columns

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested mappings, it is kind ugly but you can hide some of the complexity in a library

```
contract Db {

    mapping (address => mapping (bytes32 => bytes32)) data;

    // 

    function getAge(address usr) public view returns (uint) {
        return getUint(usr, keccak256('age'));
    }

    function setAge(address usr, uint age) public {
        setUint(usr, keccak256('age'), age);
    }

    function getName(address usr) public view returns (string) {
        return getString(usr, keccak256('name'));
    }

    function setName(address usr, string name) public {
        setString(usr, keccak256('name'), name);
    }

    // Low level access/storage

    function getUint(address usr, bytes32 ky) internal view returns (uint) {
        return uint(data[usr][ky]);
    }

    function setUint(address usr, bytes32 ky, uint val) internal {
        data[usr][ky] = bytes32(val);
    }

    function getString(address usr, bytes32 ky) internal view returns (string) {
        return bytes32ToString(data[usr][ky]);
    }

    function setString(address usr, bytes32 ky, string val) internal {
        data[usr][ky] = stringToBytes32(val);
    }

    // Utility functions to pack/unpack a string into bytes32

    function bytes32ToString(bytes32) internal returns (string) {
         ..
    }

    function stringToBytes32(string) internal returns (bytes32) {
         ..
    }

}
```